# How can I use a php file to display an HTML menu div in other HTML pages?

Tags: php, html, wamp

I have an index.html file, a menu.php file, and a testing.php file. I'm working on a simple web application for storing contacts into a database and (eventually) displaying them in a nicely formatted html page on my server. I'm using the WAMP stack to learn. After a lot of trial and error, I've finally got access to my database and I can insert new contacts. I want to be able to display a navigation menu at the top of every page, though, so that I can go back to the main page after adding a contact. That way I can add as many contacts as I want.

Here is the index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="menu">
    <?php include 'menu.php' ?>
    </div>
    <form action="testing.php" method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"></br>
        Phone Number: <input type='text' name="number"></br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the menu.php file:

```
<style type = "text/css"> 
.menu{
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    float:right;
    height: 20px;
}
</style>
<div class = "menu">
    <?php
    echo '<a href="index.html">Home</a> -
    <a href ="/test.php">Test</a> - 
    <a href ="http:/www.google.com">Google</a>';
    ?>
</div>
```

Here is the testing.php file that writes to the database:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$phonenumber = $_POST["number"];
$data = array('name' => $name, 'phonenumber' => $phonenumber);

try {
    echo '<h1>Attempting connection to database.</h1>';
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=TestDev', "root", "pass*");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $STH = $conn -> prepare("INSERT INTO tblContacts (Name, PhoneNumber)     VALUES (:name, :phonenumber)");    
    $STH -> execute($data);

}catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '<h1>Not connected to database.</h1>';
    $connectedBool = false;
}
?>
```

Why doesn't the menu show up in the pages I've included the php file in? Is there a better way to make pages and have a menu in each page? I'd appreciate any nudge in the right direction, perhaps towards a textbook or good documentation source for learning this kind of thing. The tutorials I've found so far have a similar solution but for some reason it isn't working for me.

Comment: Change your index.html to index.php

Comment: if you see `<?php include 'menu.php' ?>` string when browse the `index.html` page then  follow @NicholasAnderson and try to rename the file to `.php`. but if there is just `<div class="menu">  </div>` in your page, we should investigate little bit more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser is rendering HTML because that's what you're giving it, index.html. In order for your wamp server to process the menu.php. You need to change the extension to .php on index.html. Basic HTML doesn't know what  is.

Comment: Thank you. So with WAMP, you can serve up an entire web app with only php files that write some HTML? Can you also use HTML files and JavaScript with a WAMP set-up? Like if I want to use HTML for forms, then have some JavaScript that calls PHP files or PHP functions?

Comment: Not necessarily, your index.html can look exactly the same as it does, mostly html. When you need dynamic elements or external data, you drop in a php snippet like you did to call menu.php.  This book saved me in college.  http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/0672329166/ref=redir_mdp_mobile/192-3663734-3302152

Comment: So I can have an index file that is completely html but with a php extension, in case I need dynamic elements or external data? And I can build the entire web-page that way? I can have php files that have only HTML and maybe some JavaScript? Thanks for the book recommendation, I'll look into it!

Comment: ...or simply instruct Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP through `.htaccess`, should the OP want to keep `index.html` as their filename.

Comment: IMO, with only basic, initial knowledge, getting into Apache configuration will only add confusion.

Comment: It's easy  through `.htaccess` - no muss, no fuss. https://encodable.com/parse_html_files_as_php/

Comment: @HandleThatError, correct. Some people do it different ways but that's the simplest way to create a PHP web page starting out.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, totally true; no muss, no fuss. But knowing what to do and understanding what you're doing are totally different things.

Comment: That's what being a developer is all about and knowing what to do in cases like these. If it's simply for fun, then by all means; the OP can simply rename it to `index.php` or even `index.shtml` and do an serverside include SSI. However, depending on the server's configuration, SSI won't parse `.php` files when included, but they do on my server. Those are options that a developer needs to know ;-)